# Integer polynomials with roots in every $\mathbb{Z}_p$ but no rational roots.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, p-adic-number-theory

I'd like to find small degree polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ having no rational roots but admitting roots in all $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for every prime $p$.

Low degree examples:

- $(x^2-q)(x^2-r)(x^2-qr)$ where $r,q$ are prime numbers such that $\left(\frac{q}{r}\right)=\left(\frac{r}{q}\right)=1$ and one of $q,r,qr$ is $1$ mod $8$ (eg 13 and 17). Indeed, this works for if $p\ne 2,q,r$ is prime, one of $q,r,qr$ must be a square mod $p$ by multplicativity of legendre symbol, all of these are nonzero so we can lift with Hensel.
  If $p=q$ or $p=r$, there is a nonzero root mod $p$ by the way we chose $q,r$. Lift this root with Hensel. If $p=2$, there is a root mod $8$ not divisible by $2$ and use Hensel again.
- [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1086123/polynomial-with-a-root-modulo-every-prime-but-not-in-mathbbq) claims that the polynomial $(x^2+31)(x^3+x+1)$ works. (proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1825623/14972))

There certainly do not exist such polynomials of degree 2, because if $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has a solution mod $p$ for all primes $p$, then $b-4ac$ is a square mod every prime and hence an integral square, so a rational solution exists.

I do not expect there to be such polynomials of degree 3 or 4, how can I show this?

Comment: Do you specifically mean polynomials in one variable? Examples such as $3x^3+4y^3+5z^3$ exist as well.

Comment: yes, I'll edit it in. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: $X^4-10x^2+1$ is an example of a degree $4$ polynomial which is reducible modulo every prime (although it doesn't have a root modulo each prime)

Comment: @Mathmo123 I believe that example is reducible in all p-adics but irreducible in the rationals. That being a bit different from what was asked.

Comment: Well, Rotman's Galois Theory says it reduces over the field with $p$ elements for every prime $p.$ pages 66-67

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1086123/polynomial-with-a-root-modulo-every-prime-but-not-in-mathbbq) contains the example $(x^2+1)(x^3+3x+1)$ of degree $5$. This is optimal: any polynomial of degree $\le 4$ is solvable by radicals, and the analogue of your argument in degree $2$ applies. [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471014/an-irreducible-f-in-mathbbzx-whose-image-in-every-mathbbz-p-mathbb) is also related.

Comment: Thanks for the links. Can you make your point for polynomials of degree $\le 4$ more precise? I can see what you mean but I have no clue how to make it rigorous.

Comment: ArtW, if you wish someone to be notified when you direct a comment at them, you need to begin the message with an at sign and the beginning (or whole) of their user I.D. I don't need to do that with you because we are dirctly beneath your question

Comment: @Mathmo123 request (to you) for more detail from the OP.

Comment: Did you state that $x^2+1$ has a root in $\Bbb Z_2$? That is not true.

Comment: Of course, I'll edit it @lubin

Comment: @mathmo123 I might be wrong, but your example $(x^2+1)(x^3+3x+1)$ does not seem to work as there is no root in $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: To elaborate on what I said about solubility by radicals: one can check that $x\in \mathbb Q$ is an $nth$ power if and only if it is an $nth$ power in $\mathbb Q_p$ for all $p$. Hence, if a polynomial $f$ is soluble by radicals, that means that it has a root in $\mathbb Z$ if and only if certain quantities in terms of the coefficients (e.g. $b^2-4ac$) are certain $nth$ powers. If this is true in every $\mathbb Q_p$, then it is true in $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @ArtW You're right. I miscopied the polynomial from the other question. It should be $(x^2+31)(x^3+x+1)$.

Comment: @Mathmo123: It's not obvious an argument can be made along those lines -- solvability by radicals can take a detour through extension fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f$ is an irreducible polynomial, then there are primes where $f$ is inert, and thus does not have a root in the corresponding finite field.

This lets us rule out the case of quadratic or cubic polynomials.

If $f$ is a reducible squarefree quartic without root, then it is the product of two irreducible quadratics. Its Galois group is either $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, or $(\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z})^2$. Either way, there exist Galois elements that have no fixed points among the roots, and thus there is some prime where $f$ does not have a root.

This argument breaks down in degree 5, which is why we see examples. Consider an irreducible cubic with Galois group $S_3$. This has a cubic and quadratic subfield, and let $f$ be the product of the two defining polynomials.

Letting $c$ denote roots of the cubic and $q$ roots of the quadratic, the only possible cycle structure that permutes the roots without fixed points is $(ccc)(qq)$; however this permutation has order six and cannot be an element of $S_3$. Consequently, $f$ has a root in every finite field.

Comment: Your very first sentence is confusing: the irreducible polynomial $x^4+1 \in \Bbb Z[X]$ is _not_ inert modulo $p$, whatever the prime $p$ is. What I can see is that an irreducible polynomial having roots mod $p$ for every $p$ must be linear — but this is far from obvious (the only proof I know is using some form of Cebotarev theorem).