# Proving that an irreducible integer polynomial has no root mod q infinitely often

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

**Theorem** Let $P(X) \in \mathbb Z[X]$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree $n > 1$. There exist infinitely many primes $q$ such that $P(X)$ has no roots mod $q$.

I had worked on this a bit but my ideas did not apply. I'm pretty stuck!

Comment: First line of body says **no** roots mod $q$, but title and rest of body seem to discuss having roots modulo a prime. So which is it? Please edit your question for consistency.

Comment: @GerryMyerson My apologies, I have corrected it. Appreciate you spotting that!

Comment: Not sure I follow the argument fully, but maybe asnwer by mercio in [Is it true that if $f(x)$ has a linear factor over $\mathbb{F}_p$ for every prime $p$, then $f(x)$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/608997/290240) can help? It mentions that "Then Cebotarev's theorem says that there are infinitely many primes $p$ for which the polynomial doesn't have a linear factor over $\Bbb F_p$.", see also discussion in comments there.