# Is the polynomial $x^5+5x-10$ is solvable by radicals over $\Bbb Q$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials, solvable-groups, quintics

I have tried many ways.This polynomial has exactly one real and four complex roots and it is in Bring-Jerrard form, the solvability of which is about finding $\varepsilon, e$ and $c$ to equate some rational expressions with $5$ and $-10$.But this is very much calculative and I could not find any way. I know it will not be solvable if the Galois group is isomorphic to $A_5$ or $S_5$ but how to show that! Please help to find way.

Comment: ? polgalois(x^5 + 5*x - 10)

%1 = [120, -1, 1, "S5"]

Comment: discriminant is 32050000, not a square. so it is not A_5.

Comment: I have vague memories of a relationship between number of roots of $x^5 + 5x - 10$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$ for $p$ prime as $p$ varies, and the Galois group of the splitting field of $x^5 + 5x - 10$.  In a quick check, it looks like I get at most three roots for each case of $7 \le p \le 61$ which suggests the Galois group is "probably" one of the smaller ones.

Comment: Yes the polynomial is irreducible mod 3, which proves the galois group has a cycle of (5) in it (a 5-cycle). Together with the complex conjugation map having a (2)(2) type you must have S_5.

Comment: I understand that the Galois group has a 5 cycle but there are 4 complex roots how it can have a transposition? It has a double trabaposition but how it has a transposition bcz I know a 5 cycle and a transposition would generate S5.Please make me understand bit clearer!

Comment: @rain1 Doesn't the dihedral group of order 10, considered as a subgroup of $S_5$ via its action on the vertices of a regular pentagon, have a 5-cycle and an element of (2)(2) type?

Comment: Looking at https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_symmetric_group:S5 the only proper subgroup there with a single orbit (necessary since the polynomial is certainly irreducible) and not contained in $A_5$ (cannot be with a non-square determinant) would be the "GA(1,5) in S5" entry $\langle (1,2,3,4,5),(2,3,5,4) \rangle$.  If that's the Galois group then https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/General_affine_group:GA(1,5) says it's solvable.

Answer (score 1):

Let's [recall](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471014/an-irreducible-f-in-mathbbzx-whose-image-in-every-mathbbz-p-mathbb/471083#471083) the following.

> **Theorem (Dedekind):** If an irreducible polynomial $f(x)$ factors $\bmod p$ into factors with degrees $d_1, d_2, \dots$, then the Galois group of $f$ contains an element of cycle type $(d_1, d_2, \dots)$.

> **Theorem (Frobenius / Chebotarev):** Every cycle type in the Galois group occurs this way, with density proportional to its density in the Galois group.

Furthermore, transitive subgroups of $S_5$ (and I think maybe also $S_6$?) are determined up to conjugacy by the cycle types of their elements, so factorizations mod a prime eventually identify all Galois groups of irreducible quintics. The complete list of transitive subgroups of $S_5$ (up to conjugacy) is

- $C_5$
- $D_5$
- The Frobenius group $x \mapsto ax + b, a \in \mathbb{F}_5^{\times}, b \in \mathbb{F}_5$
- $A_5$
- $S_5$.

Using WolframAlpha we find that $f(x) = x^5 + 5x - 10$ is

- irreducible $\bmod 3$, so the Galois group contains a $5$-cycle (but this already follows from transitivity),
- a product of an irreducible quadratic and cubic $\bmod 7$, so the Galois group contains a permutation of cycle type $(2, 3)$

and we can stop here: already $S_5$ is the only transitive subgroup of $S_5$ containing an element of cycle type $(2, 3)$.

Comment: Hmm... or from my results just on number of roots in $\mathbb{F}_p$, there are exactly three roots mod 31 which would imply the Galois group must contain a transposition.

Comment: Yep, that's also enough.

Comment: Thanks. can you please tell me the cubuc and quadratic factors in mod 7?

Comment: Here's the WolframAlpha query: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+x%5E5+%2B+5x+-+10+mod+7

It's $(x^2 + 2x + 5)(x^3 + 5x^2 + 6x + 5) \bmod 7$.

Comment: Ohh thanks a lot for your help.